# how to open edmx file in design view?

Tags: c#-3.0

Can someone please suggest that how can I open edmx file in design view. This is evrytime opening in XML view?

Comment: Have you found the solution? I am facing the same problem.

Answer (score 10):

Right-click on the item and select "Open With..." - that should offer you the designer. You can also set the default from that dialog too.

I assume you're using a version of Visual Studio which supports the EDMX designer...

Answer (score 2):

If it doesn't open it automatically, you probably don't have the SQL Server Data Tools installed.

You need to modify your Visual Studio 2012 install and select SQL Server Data Tools from the optional features list, which includes the EF Designer.

Or, [here's](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/jj650015) a link to get it directly.

Answer (score 0):

What is the source of your EDMX file?

If your file is from the $metadata endpoint of an OData service, then you can't open it in Visual Studio's EDM Designer. The OData metadata format is indeed EDMX but it is not compatible with Entity Framework's EDMX format.

Comment: this is my scenario. do you still find there's no way to visualize the EDMX from such a source

Comment: @bkwdesign: Didn't try it lately. My last (unsuccessful) trials were with VS 2017.

Comment: I mentioned this in another SO thread yesterday, but, this may be the closest thing out there for modern tooling: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SAPSE.vsc-extension-odata-csdl-modeler